# Jave code replaces accented letters by interrogation points

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

A very basic problem that I've encountered in a project and it reoccured in this basic code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Special {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Donner le mot");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
        String w = sc.next();
        System.out.println(w);
    }
}
```

So I insert a string containing normal alphabetic letters and accented letters that are used in French (é,ç,ù...),  the problem I faced is in the printed output which displays the normal letters as they are and prints an interrogation point "?" at the place of each accented letter.
The compilation lines are those as usual:

```
javac Special.java
java Special
```

it's noteowrthy that I made sure to save the file in **UTF-8** encoding format.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: That is not an issue with your program but with the shell/terminal that you are running this in. That terminal does not handle utf8 correctly.

Comment: Save the output in a file and then open it to check the value - this will prove the problem you see is with the terminal program outputting the string and not with your Java code

Comment: *it's noteowrthy that I made sure to save the file in UTF-8 encoding format.* That will make no difference - it would be the same file if you'd saved it in, say Latin1. The import thing is *where* your output is shown - and you haven't told us that...

Comment: `java -XshowSettings:all 2>&1 | grep "stdout\.encoding"` in Unixes or `java -XshowSettings:all  | findstr "stdout\.encoding"` in Windows will show you the encoding that will be used to print to the terminal. If that's different to what your terminal is *set* to output, then you will probably have a problem

Comment: @g00se I did run it on both vscode and cmd, as well as an online compiler.. it was the same result. I verified my environment settings through the provided command and it got me "file.encoding = UTF-8"

Comment: `file.encoding` is related, but different

Answer (score 0):

Your program is written correctly!

Try checking what your environment settings are. Here is example how you can do it:

```java
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get the default charset for the terminal
        Charset terminalCharset = Charset.defaultCharset();
        System.out.println("Terminal Charset: " + terminalCharset.displayName());

        // Get all available charsets for the current system
        Map<String, Charset> availableCharsets = Charset.availableCharsets();
        System.out.println("Available Charsets:");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Charset> entry : availableCharsets.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().displayName());
        }
    }
}
```